# Rails 3 - remote delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In an ERB Rails view

`<%= link_to("Destroy", foos_path(1), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?") %>`

With a link_to like the above you can process the delete for a foo with an ID of 1.
How do make it remote and (a) still control being redirected to a page of my control or (b) call custom JavaScript (the goal of which would be jQuery to refresh a list)

Comment: Have you try adding :remote => true to your link?

Comment: but how do you add a :do_this_after_that_call: run_this();

Comment: If anyone knows the idiomatic way of doing this in Rails I'd love to know. For now I'm having to write custom JavaScript/jQuery with a handwritten DELETE request triggered from a 'click' event

Comment: If you want the page redirected then why does it need to be a remote request?  What are you going to use the remote request for?

Comment: Lets say I just want to run a jQuery load - $("#someDiv").load(url); on an area of the page after the remote call runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:remote => true` to the link_to will create a remote link.

In your controller method at the end put

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render "my_method"}
end
```

You can omit the name of the ajax file if it's the same name as the method.

In my_method.js.erb simply call javascript functions, and you can embed erb ie:

```
$("#someDiv").load(<%= @some_value $>);
```

You can redirect to another page using standard javascript/jquery if you choose.

Comment: you are the man! I was using format.json and never get value in template.js